# Rewrite everything to index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-505

This is a quick question. How do I change the `.htaccess` file to rewrite everything to redirect it to the `index.php` file?

When I'm removing the line of `RewriteCond` I'll get an `505 Internal Server Error`.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L,NC]
```

- `RewriteCond` will skip this rewrite for image/css/js files.
- Negative Expression `!^index\.php$` means match anything except `index.php`.

Comment: Does this redirect images somehow also? Because I only want that non-image files should be rewritten.

Comment: Check my updated answer to ignore css/js/image files.